# Append XmlElement InnerXml to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

Some errors in Visual Studio are the most helpful things with telling me how to solve it, but others are pure evil.

I am trying to build an `XmlDocument` for a list of items that my code needs to process.

There is a method that brings back a list of items such as below;

```
<searchResult>
 <item id="1"/>
 <item id="2"/>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 <item id="20"/>
</searchResult>
```

This result gets returned to me as an `XmlElement`.

```
XmlElement searchResult = returnSearchResult();
```

The `returnSearchResult` method gets returned multiple times. What I need to do is grab all the `item` elements from the `searchResult` file and append it to my `XmlDocument`.

Hopefully I have made a bit of sense. The only thing that I can't change is how the method `returnSearchResult()` returns the result. The rest is my code and I can play around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot if frustration I have fixed my problem.

```
XmlNodeList searchResultNodes = searchResult.ChildNodes;
                        foreach (XmlNode node in searchResultNodes)
                        {
                            XmlElement nodeXml = GetElement(node.OuterXml);
                            ProcessList.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ProcessList.ImportNode(nodeXml, false));
                        }
```

The main thing that I was missing was the importnode. This has solved all my problems.